# I wrote this code according to a book and I have followed all steps of it. Can you tell me how to fix this point?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\XeLaTeXlinebreaklocale "khm"
\XeLaTeXlinebreakskip​​ =0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\setmainfont[Scale=0.84,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS System}
\setmathrm{Time New Roman}
\newcommand{\en}{\fontspec{Time New Roman}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\kos}{\fontspec[Scale=0.84,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS System}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\kml}{\fontspec[Scale=0.84,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS Moul Light}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
    សរសេរអត្ថបទនៅទីនេះ
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with xelatex (the first will brreak the font handling, the second does nothing other than generate a warning that it should not be used. It is best to also avoid `\usepackage{ucs}` and `\usepackage{xltxtra}` unless you need them for legacy compatibility and just use `\usepackage{fontspec}`  . This is the default, so not needed `\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}`   Other than that you have given no indication of what problem you had, what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

`\XeLaTeXlinebreaklocale`  is undefined, I assume you intended `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`  also in the XeTeXlineskip setting you had some invisible zero width space characters.

This runs without errror for me other than I get font errors as I do not have the fonts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

%no \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%no \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% avoid \usepackage{ucs}
% avoid \usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% default \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

% typo\XeLaTeXlinebreaklocale "khm"
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "khm"

%typo \XeLaTeXlinebreakskip​​ also zero width spaces U+200B
% \XeTeXlinebreakskip​​ 0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt

\setmainfont[Scale=0.84,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS System}
\setmathrm{Time New Roman}
\newcommand{\en}{\fontspec{Time New Roman}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\kos}{\fontspec[Scale=0.84,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS System}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\kml}{\fontspec[Scale=0.84,Script=Khmer]{Khmer OS Moul Light}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
    សរសេរអត្ថបទនៅទីនេះ
\end{document}
```